# Pushing to Git and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Hi guys I have a question. When I push to **Git** I do:

```
git add .
git commit -m "My message"
git push origin master
```

and right after that if I repeat the previous steps to push to **Heroku** I get:

```
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

but if I run:

```
git push heroku master
```

it star doing a bunch of things like `Installing dependencies`, etc. that are unnecessary.

What's the right way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git add .
git commit -m "My message"
git push origin master
```

The above commits your work and send it to git. To deploy your application (from git to heroku) you use the following:

```
git push heroku master
```

It will send the code in your git (branch master) to heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Only push to `heroku master` when you want to deploy your code to Heroku. Otherwise, simply push your code to `origin`.  Once you are ready to deploy again, push to heroku.